# Best practice in css for a single full-width column with image in Bootstrap inside a container?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What is a best practice for this kind of full-width column with image inside (left column - col1). I need it to stick it to the left margin. Col 2 must have the bootstrap gutter.

[image]

Comment: Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: @JordiVicens Bootstrap4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.padded-left {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 5% 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 padded-left">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Le800MwaL.jpg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-6">
     <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```